# Question about variance stabilizing transformation

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, delta-method

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, $\ldots$ iid, $\sim$ $N(\theta,\sigma^2)$; $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ unknown, $\sigma > 0$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ given. $g(\theta) := P(X_i > a)$.

We want to estimate $g(\theta)$ using $[X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n]^{\prime}$ with $\hat{g}_n := \Phi \left( \frac{\bar{X_n}-a}{\sigma} \right)$ where $\Phi$ is the distribution function of $N(0,1)$.

I have to show that $\sqrt{n}\left( \hat{g}_n - g(\theta) \right)^2 \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0,v^2)$ and determine $v > 0$.

But I don't understand how I have to modify the delta-method that it works for $()^2$ or maybe there is another way to show this.

Comment: Is there a typo? How do the $X_i$ depend on $\theta$?

Comment: No they only define $g(\theta)$ like that and they only want a estimate for $g(\theta)$ and not $\theta$.

Comment: No I asked and he means $P(X_i > a)$.

Comment: Are you sure about the square $()^2$?

Comment: As far as I know yes.

Comment: Wondering why you mention a variance stabilizing transform. You have $g(\theta)=\Phi\left(\frac{\theta-a}{\sigma}\right)$. So if $\hat\theta=\overline X_n$ be the estimator of $\theta$, then  $\hat g_n=g(\hat\theta)$.

We trivially have $\sqrt n(\hat\theta-\theta)\stackrel{d}\longrightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$. And by delta method, $$\sqrt n(g(\hat\theta)-g(\theta))\stackrel{d}\longrightarrow N(0,\sigma^2[g'(\theta)]^2)$$ Not sure about the square though.

Comment: Im not sure either I ask again and post the solution later.